# Calling one function within another function

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to call one bash function from within another bash function and it is not working as expected :

```
#/bin/bash
function func1(){
    echo "func1 : arg = ${1}"
    return 1
}
function func2(){
    echo "func2 : arg = ${1}"
    local var=func1 "${1}"
    echo "func2 : value = $var"
}
func2 "xyz"
```

and the current output is :

```
Current output :
func2 : arg = xyz
func2 : value = func1
```

Question : how can I modify the program above so as to get the following output ? :

```
Desired output : 
func2 : arg = xyz
func1 : arg = xyz
func2 : value = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `func2` definition to the following:

```
function func2 () {
    echo "func2 : arg = ${1}"
    func1 "${1}"
    local var=$?
    echo "func2 : value = $var"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Functions in Bash do not work in the same way as functions in many other languages, they can only return an integer between 0 and 255.  This is grabbed using `$?` after the function call.  If you want to get some other value, for example a string, call it in a sub-shell:

```
local var=$(func1 "${1}")
```

will get the stdout (from `echo` statements) from the function into `$var`.

By the way, function syntax is:

```
function func1 { ... }
```

or

```
func1() { ... }
```

Comment: Yes that was a very nice explanation. Thanks also for the pointers on the function syntax.

Comment: p.s. if you wanted your function to return something greater than 255, how would one go about this in bash?

Comment: Ah found the result at http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions : "To return values, you can set a global variable with the result, or use command substitution, or you can pass in the name of a variable to use as the result variable.". Thanks

Comment: By the way you can use built-in var `$FUNCNAME` inside your function to get your function's name.

Answer (score 0):

This note may be useful because it is related somehow, the keyword return in function is used to return not the value, but the status of the function (fail or success):

```
function fun() {
    return 1
}

if ! fun; then
    echo "Fail"
fi
```

Also, keep in mind that by default any function returns the exit code of the last command that was executed by that function:

```
function fun() {
   echo "hello, World!"
   cat some_file_that_does_not_exist # exit code 1
}

if ! fun; then
    echo "Fail"
fi
```

But for your task, @choroba gave you the right answer.